# How to retrieve date from firebase to a textview (Android studio)?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is how I am posting date to firebase:

```java
final long PostTime = new Date().getTime();
```

and

```java
mDatabaseUsers.child(userID).child("transdate").setValue(PostTime);
```

I am posting it successfully, and the date is shown like this

[image: screenshot]

I am able to fetch other data using this code:

```java
String currentUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference uDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
uDatabaseReference.child(currentUid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String u_name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
        String u_email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
        int post_balance = dataSnapshot.child("balance").getValue(Integer.class);
        String bss = String.valueOf(post_balance);

        tvname.setText(u_name);
        tvemail.setText(u_email);
        tvbalance.setText(bss);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

My problem now is on date. I do not know how to fetch it. I want my date to show in this format: `dd:MM:yyyy`

How can I fetch the date from the firebase?

Comment: if you could paste here the sample of one entity in the firebase db, at least how you are keeping date in firebase, is it string or date time or time stamp?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fetch your millisecond and convert to specific date format

```
long u_date_millis = dataSnapshot.child("date").getValue(Long.class);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy");
String myPrintDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(u_date_millis )));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save date in dd/mm/yy. Get date like this:

```
    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String val = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()); // ex: 25/10/2020
```

Comment: Why would you replace the `/` with `+` upon saving?

Comment: When I was using / in firebase, firebase was creating child inspite of saving. child("24/12/11") was saved like .24.child(12.child(11))

Comment: That's when you use it in a key, as `/` is used as a separator there. Here it's used in a value, where that is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the simplest way to get the date and time pre-formatted**
`String date = String.valueOf(Build.TIME);`